# Conflict on composer require of behat/mink

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4, behat

When I try to install *Mink* (using `composer require --dev behat/mink`) I get the message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - behat/mink v1.7.1 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.1|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - behat/mink v1.7.0 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.1 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for behat/mink ^1.7 -> satisfiable by behat/mink[v1.7.0, v1.7.1].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content
```

What I found is that there is a conflict with `symfony/css-selector`.

If I run `composer show symfony/css-selector` the version shown is **v4.2.1**, so I think this is the problem.

Also, when I run `composer why symfony/css-selector` it returns:

```
symfony/test-pack  v1.0.5  requires  symfony/css-selector (*)
```

Is there any way of solving this conflict without removing the `symfony/test-pack`?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/minkphp/Mink/pull/749#issuecomment-351402449, Mink has support for Symfony 4, but not released yet. You can using `"behat/mink": "~1.7@dev"` to install latest dev code for trial.